# Laplace Transforms

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Solve the initial value problem for y(t) using Laplace Transforms.

[image]

$$L\{y''+3y'\}=L\{f(t)\}$$

$$s^2Y-sy(0)-sy'(0)+3(sY-sy(0))=L\{t\}+L\{1\}-L\{u4(t)(t-4)\}-5L{u8(t)}$$

$$Y(s^2+3s)=(1/s^2)+(1/s)-(1/s^2)e^{-4s}-5(1/s)e^{-8s}$$

Comment: I wanted to add what I've gotten so far that I believe is correct. I've tried multiple ways using partial fraction decomposition in order to get it into a form that the inverse laplace transform can be used but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: You need to write $Y$ as a rational function before you can use partial fractions.

Comment: So divide by the (s^2+3s)?

Comment: And then use partial fractions (I haven't checked your formulae above, especially of $f$).

Comment: would the partial fractions be using 1/(s^2)((s^2)+3s) ? I think that's where I'm getting stuck

Comment: Assuming that I computed correctly, I have expanded the partial fractions below.

Answer (score 0):

You can write
${1 \over s(s^2+3s)} = {1 \over 9(s+3)} - { 1 \over 9s} + {1 \over 3 s^2}$ and
${1 \over s^2(s^2+3s)} = -{1 \over 27(s+3)} + { 1 \over 27s} - {1 \over 9 s^2}+ {1 \over 3 s^3}$.

Comment: Thank you I think I am on the right track now!